# Laravel Eloquent Join On Exists Query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to achieve this query

```
'SELECT  u2.*,EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM relationships r WHERE r.following_id = u1.id AND r.follower_id = u2.id) AS friend
FROM users u1
JOIN users u2 ON EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM relationships r WHERE r.follower_id = u1.id AND r.following_id = u2.id)
WHERE u1.id = 38'
```

with laravel eloquent ORM but I am having issue with having JOIN ON EXISTS with given functions of eloquent ORM , is it possible to achieve it ?

Comment: I deleted my last comment as I misread your question, but this just doesn't sit quite right with me. Maybe it works, but maybe if this query is optimized the translation to Eloquent ORM with be more obvious? I'm not the SQL expert you need though; never seen a `JOIN x ON EXISTS` before, usually either `JOIN` or `EXISTS`

Comment: @TCooper but query works pretty normal at first It was weird for me too but it works idk why you think its wrong ?

Comment: I have to leave this to someone better with SQL is all - I was hoping what I wrote may help another answer but I'm really unsure. What you have could very well be optimal, I'm just not familiar